# swap! alter and alike

Tags: clojure

I am having a problem understanding how these functions update the underlying ref, atom etc.

The docs say: 
(apply f current-value-of-identity args)

```
(def one (atom 0))
(swap! one inc) ;; => 1
```

So I am wondering how it got "expanded" to the apply form. It's not mentioned what exactly 'args' in the apply form is. Is it a sequence of arguments or are these separate values?

Was it "expanded" to:

```
(apply inc 0) ; obviously this wouldnt work, so that leaves only one possibility
(apply inc 0 '())


(swap! one + 1 2 3) ;; #=> 7
```

Was it:

```
(apply + 1 1 2 3 '()) ;or
(apply + 1 [1 2 3])

(def two (atom []))
(swap! two conj 10 20) ;; #=> [10 20]
```

Was it:

```
(apply conj [] [10 20]) ;or
(apply conj [] 10 20 '())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The passage you quoted from `swap!`'s docstring means that what happens is the equivalent of swapping in a new value for the Atom obtained from the old one with `(apply f old-value args)`, where `args` is a seq of all additional arguments passed to `swap!`.

What actually happens is different, but that's just an implementation detail. For the sake of curiosity: Atoms have a Java method called `swap`, which is overloaded to take from one to four arguments. The first one is always an `IFn` (the `f` passed to `swap!`); the second and third, in present, are the first two extra arguments to that `IFn`; the fourth, if present, is an `ISeq` of extra arguments beyond the first two. `apply` is never involved and the fixed arity cases don't even call the `IFn`'s `applyTo` method (they just use `invoke`). This improves performance in the common case where not too many extra arguments are passed to `swap!`.